# Android - Split Drawable

Tags: android, image, gridview, grid, split

I am attempting to split an image into pieces, lets say for example 16 chunks (4x4).

I have found so many examples with java, but Android does not have BufferedImage and what not... I think.

I have a decent IDEA on how to, but I don't really know where to start.

Should I use a bitmap or a drawable?

Is there a method to split or will I have to make a custom method?

Should I use a GridView to hold the split images?

I don't want to com across as newbish and wanting to have someone do this for me, I want the satisfaction of doing it myself, but I don't have to much of an idea where to start since I am new to graphics in Java and Android.

Hopefully most of my questions are answerable and maybe even have examples available that I can't find for some reason.

Comment: Are you trying to create some type of tile system, or are you just wanting to draw different parts of the image at a time. What are you using it for?

Comment: I am attempting to create a tile system.

My idea is to split the image and add it in to a GridView.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need this

```
void createImageArrays()
{
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image);
    Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 240, 240, true);

    bitmapsArray[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 0, 0, 80, 80);
    bitmapsArray[1] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 80, 0, 80, 80);
    bitmapsArray[2] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 160, 0, 80, 80);
    bitmapsArray[3] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 0, 80, 80, 80);
    bitmapsArray[4] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 80, 80, 80, 80);
    bitmapsArray[5] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 160, 80, 80, 80);
    bitmapsArray[6] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 0, 160, 80, 80);
    bitmapsArray[7] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 80, 160, 80, 80);
    bitmapsArray[8] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, 160, 160, 80, 80);

}
```

The original image is 240x240 and I divided it into 9 pieces of 80x80

Answer (score 2):

BufferedImage in Java SE is like a Bitmap in Android. Drawable is just an interface that tells you that something is drawable. It can be a bitmap, shape, color, etc.

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense. Thank you Yuku :)